# Multithreaded debugging with PyCharm

Tags: multithreading, debugging, pycharm

I tried to debug a multithreaded python application. I setup a breakpoint in a second thread and started debugging using `PyCharm 2.7.3`.

Nevertheless I'm not able to stop at the breakpoint. How to archive multithreaded debugging with PyCharm?

Answer (score 0):

PyCharm 2 does not have good support (like the one you seek) for multithreaded debugging. PyCharm 3 does though.